# No Google Analytics History available for some client IDs

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I use the GoogleAnalyticsR R library for calling the Google Analytics API to extract the client history for some Google Analytics clientID. This seems however like a general problem with either the API or how Google Analytics saves the Web History data of Visitors.

For some ga clids I get no history but an error instead: 
`ga_clientid_activity(ids="1919844353.15xxxxxxxx" , viewId =138xxxxx, id_type = "CLIENT_ID")`
Output:
`Request Status Code: 400`

Why is the Visitor History missing or not extractable via the API?

Comment: A 400 "Bad Request" really does point to problems with the library rather than a problem with the API.

Comment: I get the 400 Error only with 50% of the client ids, and those are always the same ids.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors, 400 is listed as "invalid parameter". For debugging it might be helpful to see what query the R library issues to the API, but in most cases when a library call returns a defined error response from an API it is not the API to blame. So there might be something odd about the affected client ids that make R behave strangely.

Comment: Use `options(googleAuthR.verbose=1)` and you can see the API request, it may help - if nothing else to help debug any errors which you can raise on the GitHub issues linked form the website.   I have not heard of it before though, and its used quite a lot so I guess the request or id is malformed somehow.